# What does "first-class" exactly mean in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I have seen so far:

1. first-class function
2. [first-class fields](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/records.html#first-class-fields)
3. [first-class module](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/first-class-modules.html)

I can understand `first-class function` and it means functions can be used as arguments, as well as values,etc.

But what's the meaning of the other two `first-class`?

What is the general meaning of `first-class` in OCaml's context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never encountered a special meaning of "first class" in the context of OCaml. It's being used in its usual sense in all the places you give. I.e., a first-class value is one that can be passed to and returned from functions.

The idea of first-class record fields seems to be that you could write a function that works for many different fields (when represented as `Field.t`). In other words, you can pass individual record fields around as independent `Field.t` values.

First-class modules are also called that because you can pass them around as independent values.

Generally, terms of art like first-class don't have an "exact" meaning. In fact I would claim that's often why they're so useful.